# How to intercept only a subset of methods, and ignore the rest (groovy)?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I want to create an object used as a closure delegate, that intercept methods called with only one String as argument, and ignore the rest of the methods.

Is it possible?

Comment: it is possible.

Comment: Show at list what you are expecting...